# Make a category on a server with a BOT inside the discord.py API

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am new to Python (and, of course to discord.py), and I didn't really find any documentation on websites or on the official Discord for this question.

I was wondering if there is any function inside discord.py that would create a category on a server (`client.get_server('295959610043531264')`)

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can create categories and channel simple with this code.

the command: !new category admin-chat

```
@client.command()
async def new(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    if arg1 == "channel":
        await guild.create_text_channel(arg2)

    elif arg1 == "category":
        await ctx.guild.create_category(arg2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only create categories with the rewrite version of discord.py ([1.0.0a](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/rewrite))

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.create_category) is the documentation for it.

This would be an example of how I would do it with the commands extension:

```
@bot.command()
async def create_category(ctx, *, name):
    await ctx.guild.create_category(name)
```